# Unexpected result in linked list reverse print using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I printed linked list in reverse order using recursion. I was playing around with the code and added another print statement above the recursion call and expected it to print the linked list in original order but it only prints the first element of the list. My linked list has the following data

```
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 -->
```

Linked list class-

```
class node_obj:
def __init__(self, d):
    self.data = d
    self.next = None
```

My recursive function-

```
def recursive_revers1(head):
if head != None:
    print('--------', head.data)
    recursive_rev(head.next)
    print(head.data)

recursive_revers1(head)
```

Output:

```
-------- 0
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

The linked list is getting reversed correctly but why is the first print statement working only ones? I expected it to print the entire list in the original order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the wrong function inside the recursion: `recursive_rev` (probably an early version of the code), but your recursive function is now called `recursive_revers1`. This works for me:

```
def recursive_revers1(head):
    if head: # recommended way to ask if something is not None
        print('--------', head.data)
        recursive_revers1(head.next) # here was the mistake
        print(head.data)

recursive_revers1(head)
```

Now in the console we get:

```
-------- 0
-------- 1
-------- 2
-------- 3
-------- 4
-------- 5
-------- 6
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried different functions but forgot to change the name inside the function.